# SVG textPath without xlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Is it possible to define the path of the textPath inline, rather than creating a def and referencing it as an xlink:href as an attribute?

```
  <defs>
    <path id="MyPath"
          d="M 100 200 
             C 200 100 300   0 400 100" />
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#MyPath"/>

  <text>
    <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
      My text along a path
    </textPath>
  </text>
```

So would it be possible to have something like

```
<text>
    <textPath path="M 100 200 C 200 100 300 0 400 100">
        My text along a path
    </textPath>
</text>
```

This does not work, but something like this?

Answer (score 4):

It's a [feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextPathElement) in the new SVG 2 specification, you'd use a path attribute.

Browsers implementation of new SVG 2 features is ongoing. The example below does work in Firefox, not sure where else though.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%">
  <text>
    <textPath path="M 100 200 C 200 100 300 0 400 100">
        My text along a path
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Has it been implemented yet? I just tried and can't get it to work.

Comment: In Firefox it has.

Comment: Side note: With SVG 2 (implementation [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408)) you can define whether the text is rendered inward or outward with the new [`side`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-TextPathElementSideAttribute) attribute on the [`textPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) element.